# SQL Server 2012 Merge Understanding what happens for distinct records with fields not included in ON

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have been digging into this for a few hours now and not having much luck finding what should happen in a merge when using a group by to get a distinct set of values is not all inclusive of what is specified in ON.

pat table(Target):

```
ID (auto incremented and assigned PK) 
PAT_Name
Birth_Date
Add_LINE_1
ADD_LINE_2
City 
State
Zip 
home_phone 
mobile_phone 
email
```

ord table (Source):

```
ID (PK, auto incremented) 
PAT_Name
Birth_Date
Add_LINE_1
ADD_LINE_2
City 
State
Zip 
Pat_home_phone 
mobile_phone 
email
... additional fields I don't use in target table
```

Merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO pat AS TARGET
USING (SELECT PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, PAT_HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL from Ord GROUP BY PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, PAT_HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.PAT_NAME = SOURCE.PAT_NAME AND TARGET.ADD_LINE_1 = SOURCE.ADD_LINE_1 AND TARGET.ADD_LINE_2 = SOURCE.ADD_LINE_2 AND TARGET.CITY = SOURCE.CITY AND TARGET.STATE = SOURCE.STATE AND TARGET.ZIP = SOURCE.ZIP
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL)
    VALUES (SOURCE.PAT_NAME, SOURCE.BIRTH_DATE, SOURCE.ADD_LINE_1, SOURCE.ADD_LINE_2, SOURCE.CITY, SOURCE.STATE, SOURCE.ZIP, SOURCE.PAT_HOME_PHONE, SOURCE.MOBILE_PHONE, SOURCE.EMAIL);
```

As you can see my ON only has name and address fields and not phones and emails.  So what is happening:

My select statement with the group by is producing records that:

1. Are matched on the address fields but have a different phone in which case are not being inserted (As expected)
2. Are not matched in the address field at the time of the query and produce two rows because the address matches but they have two separate phone numbers so both rows are being inserted.  I end up with two rows with the same address fields(The fields in my ON) but with different numbers.

So my question/clarification is does the merge always insert anything that, in this case since I am using when not matched, doesn't match at time of query?  Since my select returned two rows with a new address and differing phone numbers it inserts both.  But if I run the same query again with an existing address and differing phone numbers they won't be inserted.

Or another way to put it?  If the select statement above returned 50 records all with the same address fields in my ON, address not in target, but 50 different phone numbers, would it always insert those 50 records into my target? It would never insert one record with a new address and see those and not insert the rest correct?

I can try to clarify:

EDIT with values:
Source table

```
Pat_name Add_Line_1 Add_Line_2   CITY   STATE  ZIP   home_phone  mobile_phone   email
Bob S    333 west                Go      CA    99521 555-5503                    bob@gmail.com
Bob S    444 east                Stop    CA    99950 555-5552                    bob@GMAIL.COM
BOB S    444 east                Stop    CA    99950 555-5560                    bob@gmail.com
```

Target Table:

```
Pat_name Add_Line_1 Add_Line_2   CITY   STATE  ZIP   home_phone  mobile_phone   email
Bob S    333 west                Go      CA    99521 555-5511                      bob@gmail.com
```

In this case when run the select will return all 3 rows which.  The first row has a match on the address fields specified in the ON so that will not be inserted even though it has a different phone number.  However, the last two rows will be inserted because when the select statement was run those address fields were not in the target so it inserts all results from the select without a match on the address fields.  It will never stop after the first one is inserted in the target because those address fields are now present correct?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add the pat_home_number and mobile_number numbers to the matching criteria like below. if not like you described members with the same name and different phone number will not be inserted as desired.

```
MERGE INTO pat AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT 
        PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2, CITY
        , STATE, ZIP, PAT_HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL 
    FROM Ord 
    GROUP BY PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2,
    CITY, STATE, ZIP, PAT_HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL
) AS SOURCE 

ON TARGET.PAT_NAME = SOURCE.PAT_NAME
AND TARGET.ADD_LINE_1 = SOURCE.ADD_LINE_1 
AND TARGET.ADD_LINE_2 = SOURCE.ADD_LINE_2 
--ADD these lines
AND TARGET.HOM = SOURCE.PAT_HOME_PHONE
AND TARGET.MOBILE_PHONE = SOURCE.MOBILE_PHONE
--
AND TARGET.CITY = SOURCE.CITY 
AND TARGET.STATE = SOURCE.STATE 
AND TARGET.ZIP = SOURCE.ZIP
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADD_LINE_1, ADD_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, HOME_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL)
    VALUES (SOURCE.PAT_NAME, SOURCE.BIRTH_DATE, SOURCE.ADD_LINE_1, SOURCE.ADD_LINE_2, SOURCE.CITY, 
    SOURCE.STATE, SOURCE.ZIP, SOURCE.PAT_HOME_PHONE, SOURCE.MOBILE_PHONE, SOURCE.EMAIL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess I am trying to verify I am understanding the order of operations. As I expanded with an example above.  Since the last two rows returned have and address not in the target table both will be inserted?  It is not since one gets inserted and then it has the address so the next won't be inserted.  It doesn't reevaluate after each insert from the same select?